# How to fix the height of rich text editor

Tags: react-native

I am using RichEditor of react-native-pell-rich-editor. I am trying to create basic rich text editor which should be scrollable but having fix UI height on the screen. The UI height start to vary as i type something in the editor. From the documentation i understand that the height grows as we type text inside the editor by default. If there is a way to change this default behavior as i require to fix the height of the RichEditor.

```
<RichEditor
  useContainer={false}
  disabled={false}
  ref={RichText}
  style={{
    minHeight: 200,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.green,
    marginBottom: 2
  }}
  placeholder={"Start Writing Here"}
  onChange={(text) => setArticle(text)}
  editorInitializedCallback={editorInitializedCallback}
  onHeightChange={handleHeightChange}
  />
```

I tried to change the minHeight to height and maxHeight but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

we need to style the container here

```
useContainer={false}
containerStyle={{ minHeight: height }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `initialHeight` attribute

```
 <RichEditor
   ...
   initialHeight={height} />
```

If you want it to take all the height of the screen, make the `height` variable store the height of the screen.